# Interrupt Lquibase Custom Change

Tags: java, migration, liquibase

How can I interrupt a liquibase custom change without adding an entry to the changlock?
The solution I found was to throw a CustomChangeException, but I don't think that's the best solution because the exception is never caught.

```
try {
            //check if there are any errors in the changelog file
            checkArguments();
            checkInvalidInfo(tablesFound, columnsRemoved, "The column "+this.getColumnName()+" doesn't exist in any of the matching tables");

        } catch (InvalidArgumentsNumberException  | InvalidInfoException ) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new CustomChangeException();
        }
```

I also tried to use `System.exit(-1)` but it added an entry to the changlock.

How can I make the interruption without marking the migration as done?

Comment: Are you implementing the custom change properly. Refer [this documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/custom-change.html) for details.

Comment: @RakhiAgrawal yes,I am